# Binding to an empty IEnumerable in FubuMVC results in a binding error

Tags: model-binding, fubumvc

I have an `IEnumerable<string>` valued property in my model, which gets values from a checkbox array. When no checkboxes are selected, Fubu responds with a binding error.

What happens is that Fubu looks for various potential value sources. When it finally checks Cookies, it throws an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException
   в FubuMVC.Core.Http.Cookies.CookieValueSource.GetChildren(String key) в c:\BuildAgent\work\ae412c8ad89b884b\src\FubuMVC.Core\Http\Cookies\CookieValueSource.cs:строка 46
   в FubuCore.Binding.RequestData.GetEnumerableRequests(String prefixOrChild) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\RequestData.cs:строка 84
   в FubuCore.Binding.BindingContext.GetEnumerableRequests(String name) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\BindingContext.cs:строка 66
   в FubuCore.Binding.CollectionPropertyBinder.EnumerableBuilder`1.FillValues(PropertyInfo property, IBindingContext context) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\CollectionPropertyBinder.cs:строка 64
   в FubuCore.Binding.CollectionPropertyBinder.Bind(PropertyInfo property, IBindingContext context) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\CollectionPropertyBinder.cs:строка 35
   в FubuCore.Binding.StandardModelBinder.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b(IPropertyContext propertyContext) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\StandardModelBinder.cs:строка 68
   в FubuCore.Binding.BindingContext.ForProperty(PropertyInfo property, Action`1 action) в c:\BuildAgent\work\4dafc5966c0aefb4\src\FubuCore\Binding\BindingContext.cs:строка 106
```

The binding code interprets this exception as a binding failure, and returns the following continuation ("Packages" is the name of the property):

```
{"success":false,"refresh":false,"errors":[{"category":null,"field":"Packages","label":"en-US_Packages","message":"Data is formatted incorrectly"}]}
```

How do I do it properly, besides adding a fake hidden field? I'm using the latest public NuGets: FubuCore 1.1.0 and FubuMVC.Core 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed recently